# Passing Variable into SASS using Encore

Tags: sass, symfony4, webpack-encore

I am working on a Symfony 4 application and using Symfony's Webpack wrapper Encore.

The application will be used to run multiple sites on one db, each one with a different theme. The themes will be versions of bootstrap 4 that have their primary variables set to a certain colour. i.e theme1 red, theme2 blue.

What is the optimum way to achieve this?

I have though about multiple CSS output files, i.e theme1.css, theme2.css and dynamically referencing these from the HTML.

I am also wondering if Encore/Webpack has the option to pass in a variable to  an SCSS file i.e:

```
.addStyleEntry('theme1', './scss/main.scss, red) // THIS WOULD OUTPUT theme1.css (RED) 
.addStyleEntry('theme2', './scss/main.scss, blue) // THIS WOULD OUTPUT theme1.css (BLUE)
```

The main.scss uses various mixins to overide the primary colours in Bootstrap, but I was wondering if a variable could be passed into main.scss.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SCSS for each theme. This way more changes can be added and maintained easily.

```
// scss/theme1.scss
$primary-color: red;
@import 'main';
```

and

```
// scss/theme2.scss
$primary-color: blue;
@import 'main';
```

Pack them with

```
.addStyleEntry(theme1, './scss/theme1.scss')
.addStyleEntry(theme2, './scss/theme2.scss')
```

and you are done.

Though there is a way to set SCSS variables with Webpack/Encore by prefixing all sass-entries with a string, I would not recommend this approach:

```
 .enableSassLoader((config) => { config.data = '$primary-color: green;' })
```

All entries will have the same prefix `$primary-color: green;` and you are polluting with styling information that should be placed in style-sheets when possible.